# how to disable UIpangesture recogniser(if any)in my nagation bar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i have enabled UIpangesture recogniser in my navigation bar for the purpose of putting a menu.But i need that only to be worked in my basic views of my menu.when we are going to the detailed view i need to disable it there only.Can any body help me in finding out how to disable the recogniser in the navigation bar if any thing present.i need to first check in the navigation bar view that is it enabled if it so i need to disable that?can anybody guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

The [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has an `enabled` property that you can use to enable/disable it while it is still attached to the `UIView`. This will prevent the callback from firing entirely.

Alternatively you could temporarily remove the gesture recogniser using the `UIView`'s `removeGestureRecognizer:` method and re-add it later.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for the UIPanGestureRecongniser you can check what is the current state of the app, i.e which view is loaded and then display your menu accordingly.

```
- (void)gestureCallback:(UIGestureRecogniser*)gesture{
    if(state == firstLevel)
       // Show the menu
    else
      // return without doing anything.
}
```

Comment: i need to check whether it is present or not because it is not added in that view.if it is present i need to disable it..

Comment: Yes in the call back you can check the condition and handle it accordingly. If you post more code or a better description, i can edit my answer.